# How to move the slider at specific position in python selenium(i found other solutions but they were either for javascript or java )?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

so this is the code that i use, it works fine but i cant move it to where i want to it seems to always give me a different amount, i want to move the slider range that im trying to slide is min:0 max:10 and i want to want to move the slider using the range(i have tried to adjust the pixel amount but no matter how much i change it it keeps going beyond the point i want it to)?

```
    slider = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input')
    move = ActionChains(driver)
    move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(45, 0).release().perform()
```

Comment: You could scroll to the element that you want to see on the screen.

Comment: im not trying to scroll to an element but im trying to make the slider slide to the range i want it to. so esentially i want to move it by range not by pixels()

Comment: if your wondering how the element looks here : <input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1"> <output>1</output>  i want the output to be 5 every time