# How to interact with default slider on a webpage using javascript or selenium- Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently trying to move this slider by a very small amount using selenium web driver:
image of slider

[image]

The html for the slider is:

```html
<div class="game-options_optionInput__TAqdI">
     <div class="game-options_slider__JwEe2">
          <div class="styles_rangeslider__y45WS styles_variantPurple__qW7Yo" aria-valuemin="0" aria- valuemax="600" aria-valuenow="10" aria-orientation="horizontal">
<div class="styles_fill__wyfWR" style="width: 14px;"></div><div class="styles_handle__zYRZ7" tabindex="0" style="left: 14px;"><div></div></div><ul class="styles_labels__5Sr0N"></ul></div></div></div>
```

image reference for the code above:
image of HTML
[image]

I tried to use the solution from
[How to move the slider at specific position in python selenium(i found other solutions but they were either for javascript or java )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729679/how-to-move-the-slider-at-specific-position-in-python-seleniumi-found-other-sol),
but as the question explains, the code ends up simply moving the slider either much further than I want it to, or completely randomly. I was hoping someone could provide me with a way to move the slider using either javascript I could run using selenium or a direct solution.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: what happens if you manually edit the html in the browser to `aria-valuenow="100"`?